# javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentic Failed while connecting to Jboss 7 server from remote client

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

I have standalone Java client(Running from within eclipse ) that I wish to connect to an external server . If the server is localhost then i see no problems at all . However whenever i try to connect to the external server where I always gets the following exception

```
- JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
- Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to remote://10.160.148.61:4447
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
```

I have tried to follow the steps mentioned [EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

The exception tells me tthere is something wrong in my configuration files related to authentication . Here is my ejb_client_properties file

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=10.160.148.61
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connection.default.username=tan
remote.connection.default.password=f2b1c3c7d3f1e224cbf6508494cf0418
```

Note : the user tan is added to my mgt.user.properties file on the server . I used add-user.bat to add a user in the server . I also added an application user . I use the same credentials to pass to the server . I cant think of anything else .

My ejb calling is as follows :

```
        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

        InitialContext aJNDI = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        Ppi handle = (Ppi) aJNDI
            .lookup("ejb:PPIEAR/PService/PConnect!com.gem.p.PConnection?stateful");
```

I see numerous threads related to the exception but unable to fix it :( Can someone help .

I also have a legitimate SSL certificate installed on the server . Do i need to do something extra to take care of that ?

Also NOTE : My server is running in standalone mode .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok I have been able to figure out the problem .

It was a case of the application user being added incorrectly on the server side . Specifically see below .

```
[userone@localhost bin]$ ./add-user.sh

 

What type of user do you wish to add?

a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)

b) Application User (application-users.properties)

(a): b

 

Enter the details of the new user to add.

Realm (ApplicationRealm) :  ApplicationRealm ---->> Careful Here . You need to type this or leave it blank . I filled an incorrect value here and things went wrong from there .

Username : testuser

Password : testpassword

Re-enter Password : testpassword

 

What roles do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none) : testrole

About to add user 'testuser' for realm 'ApplicationRealm'

 

Is this correct yes/no? yes

 

Added user 'testuser' to file '/home/userone/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties'

Added user 'testuser' to file '/home/userone/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/domain/configuration/application-users.properties'

Added user 'testuser' with roles testrole to file '/home/userone/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application-roles.properties'

Added user 'testuser' with roles testrole to file '/home/userone/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/domain/configuration/application-roles.properties'

.

.
```

I took me a long time to figure this out . Helpful link for the same :: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1466

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do

```
final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

InitialContext aJNDI = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
```

with a username that has access.

The same can be provided in jndi.properties, see [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project)

Comment: Well i tried but still no success . I am confused as regards to who is a legitimate user . I had a management user ( reflected in mgmt-user.properties file as well as an application user ( reflected in application-user.properties file ) I tried both still no success :( .