# Nightmare with Jboss 7.1.1 Final

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

I've been struggling with JBossAS and EJB, but can't solve the simplest question.

I've looked through a lot of manuals, tutorial, guidelines, blogs and couldn't find the answer.

I wrote two apps: server-side.jar and client-app. 1st app was assebled by maven and deployed on Jboss. Here it is:

RemoteCalculator.java:

```
package com.calculator;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

public interface RemoteCalculator {
    int add( int op1, int op2 );
}
```

CalculatorBean.java:

```
package com.calculator;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Remote(RemoteCalculator.class)
public class CalculatorBean implements RemoteCalculator {
    @Override
    public int add( int op1, int op2 ) {
        return op1 + op2;
    }
}
```

---

I've assembled "ejb-remote-stateless-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" and put it on Jboss. Satrted AS and have got "ejb-remote-stateless-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.deployed". Then I created 2nd simple console app - client for invocation CalculatorBean:

```
import com.calculator.RemoteCalculator;
import org.jboss.sasl.JBossSaslProvider;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class EJBClient {
    private static void invokeStatelessBean() throws NamingException {
        RemoteCalculator statelessRemoteCalculator = lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator();
        int sum = statelessRemoteCalculator.add( 3, 4 );
        System.out.println( "sum = " + sum );
    }

private static RemoteCalculator lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator() throws NamingException {
    Security.addProvider( new JBossSaslProvider() );
    final Hashtable<String, String> p = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    p.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447" );
    p.put( Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" );
    p.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin" );
    p.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "jboss" );
    p.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" );
    final Context context = new InitialContext( p );

    return ( RemoteCalculator ) context
            .lookup( "java:/ejb-remote-stateless-1.0-SNAPSHOT/CalculatorBean!com.calculator.RemoteCalculator" );
}

public static void main( String... args ) {
    try {
        invokeStatelessBean();
    } catch ( NamingException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

}

And I've got this exception:

```
ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: 

Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed]
```

I begg you to say me what is wrong? What have I done wrong? Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've found the error! It was because of using wrong login/pass. I used admin-righted (managment) user.

I created "aplication user" and everything was gonna well!!!

Comment: also described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129836/javax-security-sasl-saslexception-authentic-failed-while-connecting-to-jboss-7