# Remoting JMX - JMX Connection to JBOSS Server not working

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I am trying to connect to Jboss Server for accessing JMX Beans programmatically.

Please refer below code for the same:

```
    HashMap<String, String[]>   environment = new HashMap();
    String[]  credentials = new String[] {"abc", "abc"};
    environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(
            "service:jmx:remoting-jmx://SERVER_URL:PORT");
    RemotingConnectorProvider provider= new RemotingConnectorProvider();
    JMXConnector jmxc = provider.newJMXConnector(url, environment);
    jmxc.connect();
```

On running this program, I am getting below exception:

> ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:365)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:214)
>       at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
>       at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:189)
>       at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:103)
>       at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
>       at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:189)
>       at org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.handleReadable(JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.java:180)
>       at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:103)
>       at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
>       at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90)
>       at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:184)
>       at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:268)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:250)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:359)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:343)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.jmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:147)
>       at org.jboss.remoting3.jmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:96)
>       at MBeanTest.main(MBeanTest.java:51)

**I think server configuration is correct as I am able to connect using visualvm.I think there is something wrong in my program.**

PS - SERVER_URL and PORT are dummy values here.

Comment: visualvm and your application connect locally ?

Comment: i am trying to connect on remote machine. visualvm is being connected but when I am doing programmatically its not working.

Comment: did you saw this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129836/javax-security-sasl-saslexception-authentic-failed-while-connecting-to-jboss-7 and this link : https://developer.jboss.org/thread/195087?_sscc=t

Comment: Issue is resolved. I was using wrong port. Thanks.